# Solution of a simple optimization problem

Tags: linear-algebra, oc.optimization-and-control, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, linear-programming

Let $\mathbf{U}_1$ and $\mathbf{U}_2$ be two arbitrary unitary matrices and $\mathbf{D}$ be a diagonal matrix. What is the solution of the following optimization problem?
\begin{align} 
\min_{\mathbf{D}}\|\mathbf{U}_1\mathbf{D}\mathbf{U}_2-\mathbf{I}\|_F ,
\end{align}
where $\mathbf{I}$ is the identity matrix and $\|\cdot\|_F$ is the Frobenius norm.

Comment: Since $U_1$ is unitary and the Frobenius norm in unitarily equivalent, the objective is equal to $\|DU_2 - U_1^H||_F$ and thus, decouples over the rows of $U_2$.

Comment: Do that again to get to $D-U_1^H U_2^H $ and you've got an explicit expression for the elements of $D$ ...